# Python 3 - How to 'convert' a function taking a dict as arguments to one which takes keyword arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, arguments, keyword-argument

I have a function `g()` with takes a dict as an argument, ex:

```
>> g({'a':'foo', 'b':'bar', 'c','baz'})
a = foo
b = bar
c = baz
```

I would like to 'convert' `g()` or create a new function `f()` from `g()` such that it would take positional arguments instead of a dictionary, ex:

```
>> f(a='foo', b='bar', c='baz')
a = foo
b = bar
c = baz
```

Background:

- My goal is to write a small API which will make it easy for users to leverage this core package: https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization.
- To use the API, users will have to provide their user-defined-function.
- My future API will provide the user-defined-function to the core package.
- The core package expects functions which take positional arguments (not a dict).
- These user-defined-function are potentially complex and will most likely take many arguments, I would rather tell users to build their functions taking dictionaries as an argument rather than a long list of positional arguments (and do some kind of transformation within my API before invoking the core package).

Or can anyone think of a better way to address this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use a decorator for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have found a simple way to solve the problem

Here is a simple function `g` taking a dict as an argument I want to 'convert':

```
>>> def g(my_dict):
        print('a:', str(my_dict['a']))
        print('b:', str(my_dict['b']))
```

A new function `f` which takes keyword arguments can easily be created from `g`:

```
>>> def f(**kwargs):
        return g(kwargs)
```

Let's try `f` with keyword args:

```
>>> f(a='foo', b='bar')
a: foo
b: bar
```

`f` will not work with positional args:

```
>>> f('foo', 'bar')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-619-505f263ccdf6> in <module>()
----> 1 f(1, 2)

TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

### Notes:

1. I originally asked the 'converted' function `f` to take **positional arguments**. After doing additional research, I found out I what I meant was  **keyword arguments**. I used the wrong terminology in the question, my apologies.
2. My attempts with decorators as proposed by @COLDSPEED were only partially successful: I was able to create a function `f` which seemed to work but somehow the rest of the code was seeing the values it returned as `None`. Feel free to comment if you have an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, what you want is a function decorator, that executes some sort of preprocessing logic before calling your function. First, create your decorator. It will receive keyword arguments and pass it to an inner function.

```
In [239]: def baz(fnc):
     ...:     def inner(**kwargs):
     ...:         fnc(kwargs)
     ...:     return inner
     ...:
```

Decorate your original function with the decorator syntax using `@...`:

```
In [240]: @baz
     ...: def foo(dict_):
     ...:     for k in dict_:
     ...:         print(k, '=', dict_[k])
     ...:
```

Call your original function:

```
In [241]: foo(a=1, b=2, c=3)

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

---

- [Decorators](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator)

Comment: Thanks @COLDSPEED for the very quick response! This looks promising, I will give it a try and let you know how that turns out.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `exec` method, because it allows you to do anything you would be able to do in code, so there isn't much extra to learn. As an example, if you insert the following code into your code, you can create a simple function which has one arguments for every index in the dictionary, and the argument identifiers are each lowercase letter of the alphabet (so this only works if you don't exceed 26 arguments

```
def MakeFunction(DictionaryToUse):
    arguments = ""#Defaults to no arguments
    for i in range(97,97+len(DictionaryToUse)):#Adds another argument per dictionary item
        arguments += chr(i) + ","
    if len(arguments) > 0:
        arguments = arguments[:-1]#Removes the last comma, if there is one
    exec("def f(" + arguments + """):
    print("hi")""",globals())#Defines a new function f so it can be called as a global function.
```

So to make a function with 3 arguments for example, you would use:

```
MakeFunction({"foo":0,"bar":10,"foobar":96})
```

and then the new function, named `f`, can be called, with 3 arguments.

```
f(1,2,3)
```

You'll have to tailor this to suit your needs obviously, replacing f with your desired function name, and adding whatever you would like the function to do instead of `print("hi")`.